# Semisimple Lie groups admitting a free algebra of invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory

Assume we work over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero.
I know that for a connected semisimple algebraic group there is an upper bound for the number of isomorphism classes of representations with free algebra of invariants (due to Popov, 1983: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=1619&option_lang=eng ).

In Algebraic Geometry IV (2010) it is stated that the connected semisimple linear groups admitting such a representation have not yet been determined. 
Does anyone know if there has been some recent work in this direction?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no further progress on the classification; this doesn't answer your question, however.    I'd suggest you provide more explicit references, e.g., to Popov's paper, which I guess is this one: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=651651   (it's freely available online in Russian but not English).   Also, *Lie group* theory probably has little to do with the question asked.   Anyway, the connected semisimple Lie groups coincide with the connected semisimple algebraic groups over an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 (Chevalley).

Comment: P.S.  Here is the link to the Russian original: http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=1619&option_lang=eng

Comment: @JimHumphreys thank you very much. I chose the tag "Lie groups" because the question is very close to "which are the semisimple lie group actions with an affine space as a quotient"

Comment: This question is slightly confusing - it took me some time to track down the passage in Algebraic Geometry IV which says that "the connected ... *admitting* ... have not yet been determined". The point is that any semisimple algebraic group admits at least one representation for which the invariants are free: the adjoint representation. When Popov & Vinberg talk about "connected semisimple linear groups satisfying (FA)" they mean: pairs $(G,V)$ where $G$ is semisimple and $V$ is a representation. So the question really is, for a fixed $G$, what is the number $\geq 1$ of such representations?